# Monthly Subscription in Android

Tags: android, date, calendar

I am new in android and I have develop an application , now I want to apply the monthly subscription for that I have to track the date and I have tried the following code

```
try {
            before = (Date)formatter.parse(date);


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Date now = new Date();

        long diff = now.getTimeInMillis() - before.getTimeInMillis();
        long days = diff / ONE_DAY;
        if(days > 30) { // More than 30 days?
             // Expired !!!
        }
```

It gives error at 
    long diff = now.getTimeInMillis() - before.getTimeInMillis();

So can you please tell me that what is the alternative of this ?

Comment: You should do that on the server side... What happens if your user changes the date on his android phone?

Comment: well yes this is the point but in that case how it will send the user to paypal screen on android ?

Comment: did google merchant provide us option to take payment from user every month ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date from the calendar:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

There are a lot of other constants you can get from `Calendar`.

Check the [`Calendar` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) out.